# No me registra el precio que esta en decimal en sqlserver está como decimal(5,2) MVC asp.net

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net, mvc, decimal

Yo intento que registre el precio con dos decimales. En un rango entre 0.01 y 100.00. Registra todo menos el precio y cuando cambié la columna precioprod a decimal(5,0) en el sql registró el precio sin decimales.Me parece que el problema está en c#. Quiero poner decimal(5,2) en el sql pero no sé cómo debo poner en C# para que lo registre. Con poner solo decimal no lo registra.

Al momento de ingresar 10.00 como precio sale en el formulario que 10.00 no es un valor valido para precio. Creo que el problema son las validaciones.

**Procedure ins_prod**

```
      ALTER procedure [dbo].[ins_prod]
      @idprod int,
      @nomprod varchar(20),
      @descprod varchar(200),
      @precioprod decimal(5,2),
      @entrada int,
      @segundo int,
      @dulce int,
      @imgprod varchar(50)
      as
      Begin
        insert into producto values(@idprod,@nomprod,@descprod,@precioprod,@entrada,@segundo,@dulce,@imgprod)
      end
```

**La clase Producto**

```
    public class Producto
{
    public Int32 idprod { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Nombre")]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Ingrese el/los Nombre(s)")]
    [MaxLength(30, ErrorMessage = "Máximo 30 caracteres")]
    [MinLength(10, ErrorMessage = "Mínimo 10 caracteres")]
    public string nomprod { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Descripción")]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Ingrese la descripción")]
    [MaxLength(200, ErrorMessage = "Máximo 200 caracteres")]
    [MinLength(10, ErrorMessage = "Mínimo 10 caracteres")]
    public string descprod { get; set; }


    [Display(Name = "Precio")]
    [Range(0.00,100.00)]
    [Required]
    public decimal precioprod { get; set; }

    public Int32 entrada { get; set; }
    public Int32 segundo { get; set; }
    public Int32 dulce { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Foto")]
    [Required]
    public string imgprod { get; set; }
```

**El Formulario**

```
@model CateringMarie.Models.Producto

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Producto", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Producto</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.idprod, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.idprod, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.idprod, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.nomprod, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.nomprod, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.nomprod, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.descprod, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.descprod, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.descprod, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.precioprod, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
         
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.precioprod, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.precioprod, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2">Tipo</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <select name="tipo" class="form-control">
                <option value="entrada">Entrada</option>
                <option value="segundo">Segundo</option>
                <option value="dulce">Postre</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.imgprod, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input type="file" name="archivo" class="form-control" accept="image/*" />
            <!--@Html.TextBox("archivo", "", new { type = "file", accept = "image/*" })-->
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

SQL-La Tabla Producto

```
if OBJECT_ID('producto') is null
create table producto(
idprod int primary key,
nomprod varchar(30),
descprod varchar(200),
precioprod decimal(5,2),
entrada int,
segundo int,
dulce int,
check (entrada >-1 and entrada<2),check (segundo >-1 and segundo<2),check (dulce >-1 and dulce<2))
go
```

**Los Metodos CRUD y Create**

```
       public string CRUD(string procedure, List<SqlParameter> arreglo = null)
    {
        //ejecuta los procedures de insert o update y debe retorna el mensaje proceso
        string mensaje = "";
        try
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(procedure, con))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddRange(arreglo.ToArray());
                con.Open();
                int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                mensaje = i + "Registro actualizado";
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException e) { mensaje = e.Message; }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
        return mensaje;
    }

        public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View(new Producto());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Producto reg, HttpPostedFileBase archivo, string tipo)
    {

        string ruta;
        /*si no has seleccionado, utilizo la imagen anterior, sino creo la nueva ruta de img seleccionada*/
        if (archivo == null)
            ruta = reg.imgprod;
        else
        {
            archivo.SaveAs(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Fotos/") + Path.GetFileName(archivo.FileName)));
            ruta = "~/Fotos/" + Path.GetFileName(archivo.FileName);
        }

        if (tipo == "entrada") { reg.entrada = 1; } else { reg.entrada = 0; }
        if (tipo == "segundo") { reg.segundo = 1; } else { reg.segundo = 0; }
        if (tipo == "dulce") { reg.dulce = 1; } else { reg.dulce = 0; }

       
        List<SqlParameter> lista = new List<SqlParameter>() {

         new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@idprod", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int, Value = reg.idprod },
         new SqlParameter(){ ParameterName="@nomprod",SqlDbType=SqlDbType.VarChar,Value=reg.nomprod},
         new SqlParameter(){ ParameterName="@descprod",SqlDbType=SqlDbType.VarChar,Value=reg.descprod},
         new SqlParameter(){ ParameterName="@precioprod",SqlDbType=SqlDbType.Decimal,Value=reg.precioprod},
         new SqlParameter(){ ParameterName="@entrada",SqlDbType=SqlDbType.Int,Value=reg.entrada},
         new SqlParameter(){ ParameterName="@segundo",SqlDbType=SqlDbType.Int,Value=reg.segundo},
         new SqlParameter(){ ParameterName="@dulce",SqlDbType=SqlDbType.Int,Value=reg.dulce},
         new SqlParameter(){ ParameterName="@imgprod",SqlDbType=SqlDbType.VarChar,Value=ruta}
        };

        ViewBag.mensaje = CRUD("ins_prod", lista);

        return View(reg);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: 1. ¿Qué valor del precio del producto llega al controlador? 2. ¿Cómo es el esquema de la tabla, seguro que tiene varios campos decimales? 3. ¿Has intentado ejecutar el SP de manera manual a nivel de base de datos sin la aplicación? Si lo intentado, ¿funciona los decimales o no? Si no funcionan a ese nivel, hay que revisar el esquema de la tabla y si funciona, cosa de ver los datos que se insertan como parámetros. Saludos.

Comment: con el procedure ins_prod puedo introducir un valor decimal en la bd desde sqlserver. El procedure si funciona. Cuando creo nuevo producto se guarda todo menos el precio. Me parece que es la validación que no me permite registrar el precio. Yo ingreso 10.00 en precio en el formulario y me dice que no es un valor valido.

Comment: Si ingreso 10.50 en el campo, ¿se envía al controlador o solo aparece el mensaje de error?

Comment: Si ingresas 10.50 en el formulario llega null al controlador. No sé si es problema de JQuery o Bootstrap quizas.

Comment: Ya descubrí el problema. Para ver si era problema de validacion de bootstrap cree un formulario desde cero, sin scripts sin css, hice cada uno de los inputs. Resultó que no era la validación del bootstrap que fallaba. Yo ingresaba el precio con el teclado numérico usando el "." como separador de decimales. Ahora probé con la coma como separador de decimales y ya ingresó el precio en la base de datos. Discúlpenme por hacerles perder tiempo.

Comment: Luego volví a poner el bootsrap y el JS y no me permitía poner la coma decimal. Busqué en google y bajé dos funciones en JQuery y al fin funcionó y se grabó en el sqlserver.